# File read in 'c' using fgets

Tags: c, string, file

If i have a text file with each line of different length, how does the following code work??

```
FILE *ptr;
char str[100];
ptr=fopen("hi.txt","r");
while(fgets(str,100,ptr)!=NULL)
{
........
........
}
```

In this code the 'str' will hold 100 characters which includes some of the characters from 2nd line of text file(if the 1st line of file is 90 chars then 10 chars from second line will also be read)..
If i am correct, can you please tell how to read exactly only one line during every ready?

Comment: That's not how `fgets` works.  The previously read line will be overwritten by the next line.  `fgets` will stop reading when it hits a new line character.

Comment: So what if the first line is more than 100 chars?

Comment: @user1762571 then `fgets` only reads up to 99 chars.

Comment: Actually, only 99 characters, it saves a character for the null byte.

Comment: so if i read only 99 characters, would  rest of the line be written in a new line in case if i read in this file and write to another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgets will read up to a single line OR the value passed in as the second parameter.

[fgets man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html)

As long as none of your lines are longer than 99 characters (saving one for the NUL terminator, your code will work as expected.

If you call fgets on a line that is longer than N-1, your next read will continue where it left off and go another 99 bytes or until it finds the end of the line.

Comment: got it.. So what is the efficient way to read a full line in one read. Is it allocating a big size array or any other way?

Comment: There's no way to guarantee you can read a full line without parsing through the file ahead of time to know how long the longest line is and allocating for the longest line (+1) or guarantee the line will never be longer than some predetermined length.

Comment: so if read it using fgetc we can detect the end of each line properly right?

Comment: that is correct, but if you don't have enough space, you may have to call it multiple times per line.  You're guaranteed, however, to have to call it AT LEAST once per line -- even if each line is empty.

Comment: ok. So in fgets if it reads only 99 characters, would rest of the line be written in a new line in case if i read  this file and write to another file

Comment: @xaxxon Huh? What do you think the `LINE_MAX` macro means/is for?

Comment: @H2CO3 i don't know, I've never heard of it.  What does it mean/is for?

Comment: @xaxxon It's the maximal number of characters in a line. If you use a buffer of that size, you're guaranteed to be able to read each line at once.

Comment: @H2CO3 what does it even mean to have a maximum number of characters in a line.  Isn't a line just defined as "stuff until you find a newline delimeter"?

Comment: @xaxxon "stuff until you find a newline delimeter (sic!) of which the size is less than or equal to the size of stuff your implementation supports".